# Как написать о Планете Цветов?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

С маленькой или большой буквы пишется слово "планета" в словосочетании "Планета Цветов"?
По правилам "планета Земля" пишется с маленькой буквы. При этом слово "Земля" может произноситься само по себе, но Планета Цветов только вместе, то есть это и есть полное название планеты.
Искала похожие названия - "Планета роботов", "Планета обезьян", но везде находила разное написание.

Answer (score 2):

"Грамота.ру" в ответе на схожий вопрос рекомендует только первую букву писать с прописной. Тогда верно: *Планета цветов* (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310238)).

**Вопрос № 310238**

> Скажите, пожалуйста, как пишутся неформальные названия космических объектов, например планет? Возможно, их можно счесть за прозвища и тогда правомерно писать все слова в названиях с прописной (кроме служебных и не первых родовых)? Марс — Красная планета, Земля — Голубая планета, какая-нибудь выдуманная Икарис — Планета Вечных Туманов...

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В закрепившихся условных названиях астрономических тел с заглавной буквы пишется первое слово, например *Красная планета*, ср. *Страна восходящего солнца* (о Японии), *Страна утренней свежести* (о Южной Корее). Так же можно писать и авторские образные сочетания, используемые как названия (например, в художественном произведении). Описательные обороты записываются строчными буквами.

Comment: Но здесь вроде бы не условное название, а единственное.

Comment: Ну, "Грамота.ру" так и пишет: "Так же можно писать и авторские образные сочетания, используемые как названия".